Object Detection Custom Model Loss Not Decreasing During Training
I'm working on an object detection project using PyTorch on Kaggel, where I'm trying to detect and recognize text in any day objects, such as traffic signs, documents, etc. I've implemented a custom model based on the EAST model architecture, using ResNet as my backbone. However, I'm encountering an issue where the loss isn't decreasing significantly during training. Here's a snippet of my training output:
...
Epoch 28/30
Training: |####################| 005/005 [100.00%] in 0.0s (1746419.0/s, ETA: 0.0s) (loss: 53.674442291259766)
Validation: |####################| 003/003 [100.00%] in 0.0s (731885.0/s, ETA: 0.0s) (loss: 52.65853627522787)
Epoch 29/30
Training: |####################| 005/005 [100.00%] in 0.0s (1104972.0/s, ETA: 0.0s) (loss: 54.1553955078125)
Validation: |####################| 003/003 [100.00%] in 0.0s (950871.0/s, ETA: 0.0s) (loss: 52.0231081644694)
Epoch 30/30
Training: |####################| 005/005 [100.00%] in 0.0s (1353912.0/s, ETA: 0.0s) (loss: 53.528507232666016)
Validation: |####################| 003/003 [100.00%] in 0.0s (1148105.0/s, ETA: 0.0s) (loss: 51.57835261027018)

I've tried the following without much success:

Adjusting the learning rate
Changing the batch size
Modifying the model architecture slightly

It doesn't make sense to me, I have assume I did everything correctly in my module, I've split apart my two detections, and return a tensor, in which, I can use it on my custom loss class and calculate it.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torchvision.models as models
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from typing import Tuple, Optional, List
import logging
from pathlib import Path

# Set up logging configuration
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("model.log", mode="w")
    ]
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class TLR(nn.Module):
    """
    Text Localization and Recognition (TLR) model with additional layers.
    
    This model uses a ResNet50 backbone and adds more convolutional layers
    for improved feature extraction and prediction.
    """

    def __init__(self, hidden_size: int = 256, input_channels: int = 1, num_classes: int = 35):
        """
        Initialize the TLR model.

        Args:
            hidden_size (int): Size of the hidden layers. Defaults to 256.
            input_channels (int): Number of input channels. Defaults to 1.
            num_classes (int): Number of classes to predict. Defaults to 35.
        """
        super(TLR, self).__init__()
        
        logger.info("Initializing TLR model")
        
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        
        # Initialize ResNet50 backbone without pretrained weights
        backbone = models.resnet50(weights=None)
        backbone.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(input_channels, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
        
        self.backbone = nn.Sequential(*list(backbone.children())[:-2])
        
        self.merge = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(2048, hidden_size, 1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_size),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(hidden_size, hidden_size, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_size),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(hidden_size, hidden_size, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_size),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        
        self.det_head = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(hidden_size, hidden_size, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_size),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(hidden_size, hidden_size // 2, 1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_size // 2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(hidden_size // 2, hidden_size // 2, 3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_size // 2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(hidden_size // 2, 4 + num_classes, 1)
        )
        
        logger.info("EnhancedTLR model initialized")

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]:
        """
        Forward pass of the EnhancedTLR model.

        Args:
            x (torch.Tensor): Input tensor of shape [batch_size, input_channels, height, width]

        Returns:
            Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]: 
                - bbox: Bounding box predictions of shape [batch_size, num_predictions, 4]
                - class_scores: Class scores of shape [batch_size, num_predictions, num_classes]
        """
        features = self.backbone(x)
        logger.debug(f"Backbone output shape: {features.shape}")
        
        merged = self.merge(features)
        logger.debug(f"Merge output shape: {merged.shape}")
        
        det_output = self.det_head(merged)
        logger.debug(f"Detection head output shape: {det_output.shape}")
        
        batch_size, _, height, width = det_output.shape
        det_output = det_output.permute(0, 2, 3, 1).contiguous()
        det_output = det_output.view(batch_size, -1, 4 + self.num_classes)
        
        bbox = torch.sigmoid(det_output[..., :4])
        class_scores = det_output[..., 4:]
        
        logger.debug(f"Output shapes - bbox: {bbox.shape}, class_scores: {class_scores.shape}")
        
        return bbox, class_scores

class TLRLoss(nn.Module):
    """
    Loss function for the TLR model, combining Smooth L1 Loss for bounding box regression
    and Cross Entropy Loss for class prediction.
    """
    def __init__(self, beta: float = 1.0):
        """
        Initialize the TLRLoss.
        Args:
            beta (float): Transition point from L1 to L2 loss. Defaults to 1.0.
        """
        super(TLRLoss, self).__init__()
        self.bbox_loss_fn = nn.SmoothL1Loss(beta=beta, reduction='sum')
        self.class_loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=-1, reduction='sum')  # Ignore padding with -1

    def forward(
        self, 
        bbox_pred: torch.Tensor, 
        bbox_target: List[torch.Tensor],
        class_scores_pred: torch.Tensor, 
        class_target: List[torch.Tensor]
    ) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]:
        """
        Compute the bounding box regression loss and class classification loss.
        
        Args:
            bbox_pred (torch.Tensor): Predicted bounding boxes of shape [batch_size, num_predictions, 4].
            bbox_target (List[torch.Tensor]): Ground truth bounding boxes for each image, 
                                              where each tensor has shape [num_boxes, 4].
            class_scores_pred (torch.Tensor): Predicted class scores of shape [batch_size, num_predictions, num_classes].
            class_target (List[torch.Tensor]): Ground truth class labels for each image, 
                                               where each tensor has shape [num_boxes].
        
        Returns:
            Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]: The bounding box regression loss and class classification loss.
        """
        batch_size = bbox_pred.size(0)
        device = bbox_pred.device
        
        # Compute total number of boxes across the batch
        total_boxes = sum(boxes.shape[0] for boxes in bbox_target)
        
        # Initialize tensors to store all ground truth boxes and labels
        all_bbox_target = torch.zeros(total_boxes, 4, device=device)
        all_class_target = torch.full((total_boxes,), -1, dtype=torch.long, device=device)
        
        # Initialize mask for valid predictions
        valid_pred_mask = torch.zeros(batch_size, bbox_pred.size(1), dtype=torch.bool, device=device)
        
        # Fill in the ground truth tensors and create the mask
        start_idx = 0
        for i, (boxes, labels) in enumerate(zip(bbox_target, class_target)):
            num_boxes = boxes.shape[0]
            all_bbox_target[start_idx:start_idx + num_boxes] = boxes
            all_class_target[start_idx:start_idx + num_boxes] = labels
            valid_pred_mask[i, :num_boxes] = True
            start_idx += num_boxes
        
        # Flatten predictions and apply mask
        bbox_pred_flat = bbox_pred[valid_pred_mask]
        class_scores_pred_flat = class_scores_pred[valid_pred_mask]
        
        # Compute losses
        bbox_loss = self.bbox_loss_fn(bbox_pred_flat, all_bbox_target)
        class_loss = self.class_loss_fn(class_scores_pred_flat, all_class_target)
        
        # Normalize losses by the total number of boxes
        bbox_loss /= total_boxes
        class_loss /= total_boxes
        
        return bbox_loss, class_loss

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Define paths
    images_path: Path = Path("/kaggle/input/license-plate-individual-character-recognition/dataset/test/images")
    annotations_path: Path = Path("/kaggle/input/license-plate-individual-character-recognition/dataset/test/annotations")
    
    # Define transformations for images
    transform: transforms.Compose = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((150, 300)),
        transforms.ToTensor()
    ])
    
    # Initialize dataset and DataLoader
    dataset: PairedDataset = PairedDataset(images_path, annotations_path, transform=transform)
    dataloader: DataLoader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, collate_fn=collate_fn)
    
    # Initialize model with custom arguments
    model: TLR = TLR(hidden_size=256, input_channels=1, num_classes=35)
    
    # Test the model
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (images, targets) in enumerate(dataloader):
            if images is None:
                continue

            logger.info(f"Processing batch {batch_idx + 1}/{len(dataloader)}")

            bbox_pred, class_pred = model(images)
            
            print(f"Batch {batch_idx + 1}:")
            print(f"Bounding box predictions shape: {bbox_pred}")
            print(f"Class predictions shape: {class_pred}")

    logger.info("Data pass completed")
    logger.info("Script execution completed")

In my training script, I split my targets, that are in a list, into their own group, each image has multiple detections. And each bounding box has its own label.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.models.detection as detection
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import random
import logging
import asyncio
from typing import Union, List, Tuple, Optional, Dict, Literal

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("trainer.log", mode="w")
    ]
)

class Trainer:
    """
    A class to handle training, validation, and testing of an object detection model.
    """

    def __init__(self, module: nn.Module, train_data_paths: List[Path], val_data_paths: List[Path],
                 test_data_paths: List[Path], image_size: Tuple[int, int] = (150, 300),
                 epochs: int = 30, batch_size: int = 64, learning_rate: float = 0.0001,
                 seed: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
        """
        Initialize the Trainer with dataset paths, hyperparameters, and device settings.

        Args:
            module (nn.Module): The model to use for training.
            train_data_paths (List[Path]): Paths to training images and annotations.
            val_data_paths (List[Path]): Paths to validation images and annotations.
            test_data_paths (List[Path]): Paths to test images and annotations.
            image_size (Tuple[int, int]): Desired image size (height, width).
            epochs (int): Number of training epochs.
            batch_size (int): Batch size for DataLoader.
            learning_rate (float): Learning rate for the optimizer.
            seed (Optional[int]): Random seed for reproducibility.
        """
        # Validate input paths
        for paths in [train_data_paths, val_data_paths, test_data_paths]:
            if not isinstance(paths, list) or len(paths) != 2 or not all(isinstance(p, Path) for p in paths):
                raise TypeError("Each data path argument must be a list of two Path instances")

        # Validate hyperparameters
        if not isinstance(image_size, tuple) or len(image_size) != 2 or not all(isinstance(i, int) for i in image_size):
            raise ValueError("image_size must be a tuple of two integers (height, width)")
        if not isinstance(epochs, int) or not isinstance(batch_size, int) or not isinstance(learning_rate, float):
            raise TypeError("epochs must be an integer, batch_size must be an integer, and learning_rate must be a float")
        if seed is not None and not isinstance(seed, int):
            raise TypeError("seed must be an integer or None")
        if not isinstance(module, nn.Module):
            raise TypeError("module must be an instance of nn.Module")

        # Set random seed if provided
        self._set_random_seed(seed)

        # Set the device to CUDA if available, otherwise use CPU
        self.device: torch.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

        # Load the model and move to device
        self.module: nn.Module = module
        self.module.to(self.device)

        # Store hyperparameters and prepare DataLoaders
        self.image_size: Tuple[int, int] = image_size
        self.epochs: int = epochs
        self.train_loader: DataLoader = self._load_data(train_data_paths, batch_size, mode="training")
        self.val_loader: DataLoader = self._load_data(val_data_paths, batch_size, mode="validation")
        self.test_loader: DataLoader = self._load_data(test_data_paths, batch_size, mode="validation")

        # Use TLRLoss as the criterion
        self.criterion = TLRLoss()
        
        # Setup optimizer and learning rate scheduler
        self.optimizer: torch.optim = torch.optim.Adam(self.module.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
        self.scheduler: torch.optim.lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(self.optimizer, step_size=3, gamma=0.1)
            
        logging.info("Trainer initialized successfully.")

    @staticmethod
    def _set_random_seed(seed: Optional[int]) -> None:
        """
        Set the random seed for reproducibility.

        Args:
            seed (Optional[int]): Random seed to set. If None, no seed is set.
        """
        if seed is not None:
            torch.manual_seed(seed)
            random.seed(seed)
            np.random.seed(seed)
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
                torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
                torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
            logging.info(f"Seed set to {seed}.")

    def _load_data(self, data_paths: List[Path], batch_size: int, mode: Literal["training", "validation"] = "training") -> DataLoader:
        """
        Load data using the specified paths and return a DataLoader.

        Args:
            data_paths (List[Path]): Paths to the images and annotations.
            batch_size (int): Number of samples per batch.
            mode (Literal["training", "validation"]): Mode specifying whether the data is for training or validation.

        Returns:
            DataLoader: A DataLoader object for the dataset.
        """
        transform: transforms.Compose = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize(self.image_size),
            transforms.RandomRotation(10) if mode == "training" else transforms.Lambda(lambda x: x),
            transforms.RandomAffine(degrees=0, translate=(0.1, 0.1), scale=(0.9, 1.1)) if mode == "training" else transforms.Lambda(lambda x: x),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5], std=[0.5])
        ])
        # Initialize the dataset with the given paths and transformations
        dataset: PairedDataset = PairedDataset(
            images_dir=data_paths[0], annotations_dir=data_paths[1], transform=transform
        )
        logging.info(f"Data loaded from {data_paths}.")
        # Return a DataLoader for the dataset
        return DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, collate_fn=collate_fn)

    async def _run_epoch_async(self, data_loader: DataLoader, mode: Literal["training", "validation"] = "training") -> float:
        """
        Run a single epoch asynchronously for training or validation.

        Args:
            data_loader (DataLoader): The DataLoader to iterate over.
            mode (Literal["training", "validation"]): Mode specifying whether the data is for training or validation.

        Returns:
            float: The average loss over the epoch.
        """
        # Set the model to training or evaluation mode based on the provided mode
        self.module.train() if mode == "training" else self.module.eval()

        # Initialize the total loss for the epoch
        total_loss: float = 0.0

        # Initialize a progress bar with asynchronous capabilities
        async with Bar(iterations=len(data_loader), title=mode.capitalize(), steps=20) as bar:
            start_time: float = asyncio.get_event_loop().time()

            # Iterate over the DataLoader, which provides batches of images and targets
            for progress, (images, targets) in enumerate(data_loader, start=1):
                # Ensure that the images are in the correct format (torch.Tensor)
                if not isinstance(images, torch.Tensor):
                    logging.warning("Images must be a torch tensor.")
                    continue

                # Move images and targets to the device (e.g., GPU)
                images = images.to(self.device)
                targets: List[Dict[str, torch.Tensor]] = [{k: v.to(self.device) for k, v in t.items()} for t in
                                                          targets]

                # Reset the gradients of the optimizer
                self.optimizer.zero_grad()

                # Enable gradient calculation only if in training mode
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(mode == "training"):
                    # Forward pass through the model
                    bbox_pred, class_pred = self.module(images)
                    
                    # Scale bounding boxes to original image size (avoid in-place operations)
                    bbox_pred = torch.stack([
                        bbox_pred[:, :, 0] * self.image_size[1],  # x_min scaled by width
                        bbox_pred[:, :, 1] * self.image_size[0],  # y_min scaled by height
                        bbox_pred[:, :, 2] * self.image_size[1],  # x_max scaled by width
                        bbox_pred[:, :, 3] * self.image_size[0],  # y_max scaled by height
                    ], dim=2)
                    
                    # Separate targets into bbox_targets and class_targets
                    bbox_target = [t['boxes'] for t in targets]
                    class_target = [t['labels'] for t in targets]
        
                    # Compute losses for bounding boxes and classes
                    bbox_loss, class_loss = self.criterion(
                        bbox_pred,
                        bbox_target,
                        class_pred,
                        class_target
                    )

                    loss = (bbox_loss + class_loss)

                if mode == "training":
                    # Backward pass
                    loss.backward()
                    self.optimizer.step()

                # Accumulate the scalar loss
                total_loss += loss.item()

            # Await progress updates for the progress bar
            await bar.update(progress, start_time)
            await bar.postfix(loss=np.divide(total_loss, progress))

        # Compute the average loss for the epoch
        avg_loss: float = np.divide(total_loss, len(data_loader))
        logging.info(f"{mode.capitalize()} epoch completed with average loss: {avg_loss:.4f}")

        return avg_loss

    async def train(self) -> None:
        """
        Train the model for the specified number of epochs.
        """
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{self.epochs}")

            logging.info(f"Starting training epoch {epoch + 1}/{self.epochs}.")

            # Run the training and validation epochs asynchronously
            train_loss: float = await self._run_epoch_async(self.train_loader, mode="training")
            logging.info(f"Training epoch {epoch + 1} completed with average loss: {train_loss:.4f}")

            val_loss: float = await self._run_epoch_async(self.val_loader, mode="validation")
            logging.info(f"Validation epoch {epoch + 1} completed with average loss: {val_loss:.4f}")

            # Update the learning rate scheduler
            self.scheduler.step()

    async def test(self) -> None:
        """
        Test the model on the test dataset.
        """
        logging.info("Starting testing.")
        # Implement testing logic here...

    async def save(self, save_path: Union[str, Path]) -> None:
        """
        Save the model to the specified path.

        Args:
            save_path (Union[str, Path]): The path where the model will be saved.
        """
        torch.save(self.module, save_path)
        print(f"Model saved at: {save_path}")
        logging.info(f"Model saved at: {save_path}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a Trainer instance with dataset paths
    trainer = Trainer(
        module=TLR(),
        train_data_paths=[Path("/kaggle/input/license-plate-individual-character-recognition/dataset/train/images"), Path("/kaggle/input/license-plate-individual-character-recognition/dataset/train/annotations")],
        val_data_paths=[Path("/kaggle/input/license-plate-individual-character-recognition/dataset/val/images"), Path("/kaggle/input/license-plate-individual-character-recognition/dataset/val/annotations")],
        test_data_paths=[Path("/kaggle/input/license-plate-individual-character-recognition/dataset/test/images"), Path("/kaggle/input/license-plate-individual-character-recognition/dataset/test/annotations")],
    )

    # Run the training, validating, testing, and saving processes asynchronously
    await trainer.train()
    await trainer.test()
    await trainer.save("recognition_model.pt")

What could be causing this stagnation in the loss, and what strategies would you recommend to improve the training process? Are there any specific debugging steps or modifications to the training loop that might help identify the root cause?

Is there any reason you're not using any pre-trained weights for your resnet backbone? resnet50 has something like 200 million parameters, and including the rest of your network that's a lot of parameters to train. With that many parameters it is typical for your loss to jump around for quite a few epochs. I'd recommend using some pre-trained weights like imagenet and freezing your resnet layers during training to see if your loss starts to improve.

@A10 I saw your message, and freezing my ResNet layers has improved my loss but was minimal. However, how exactly do pretrained weights like ImageNet help me achieve a simple yet efficient OCR? I'm dumbfounded in this, training logic, because I don't want it to take longer for me to train, and have my model contain unnecessary parameters that will take execution speed and I'm not going to even use. My dataset contains 500 images—isn't that sufficient?

I'd recommend you take some time to research "transfer learning" -- a technique that allows you to use pre-trained networks for custom applications. By using, and freezing, the resnet layers the assumption is those layers act as feature selectors which will improve the performance of the task in your custom layers. By freezing resnet, you still have those parameters, but they are not optimized at training time. 500 images is likely insufficient for reasonable generation without some sort of transfer learning in place.

If your concern is minimal parameters and fast execution speed -- you can take a look at transfer learning with something like mobile or efficient net, or a custom approach without pre-trained networks. For most applications, the only reason to use a pre-defined architecture is to take advantage of the pre-trained weights, other wise you're essentially starting from scratch.
